# how to set visual studio test traits in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a Python project in Visual Studio 2019. I have created some unit tests but would like to organize them by Traits in the test explorer. I know in C# I can simply add a trait like this [my_trait]. But how do I set these traits in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think unittest implements anything like test markers, so this feature isn't currently available in PTVS.

Pytest is another test framework that we support and it does allow test markers but I believe we only parse the built in traits like skip, skip-if etc.

I would suggest switching to pytest and requesting custom test markers here https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS